# Unclear output by riscv objdump -d

Tags: linux, assembly, elf, riscv, objdump

Now I am trying to understand the RISC-V ISA but I have an unclear point about the machine code and assembly.

I have written a C code like this:

```c
int main() {
    return 42;
}
```

Then, I produced the .s file by this command:

`$ /opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -S 42.c`

The output was:

```
        .file   "42.c"
        .option nopic
        .text
        .align  1
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        addi    sp,sp,-16
        sd      s0,8(sp)
        addi    s0,sp,16
        li      a5,42
        mv      a0,a5
        ld      s0,8(sp)
        addi    sp,sp,16
        jr      ra
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (g5964b5cd727) 11.1.0"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Now, I run following command to produce an elf.

`$ /opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -nostdlib -o 42 42.s`

So, a binary file is produced. I tried to read that by objdump like this:

`$ /opt/riscv/bin/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-objdump -d 42`

So the output was like this:

```
42:     file format elf64-littleriscv


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000000100b0 <main>:
   100b0:       1141                    addi    sp,sp,-16
   100b2:       e422                    sd      s0,8(sp)
   100b4:       0800                    addi    s0,sp,16
   100b6:       02a00793                li      a5,42
   100ba:       853e                    mv      a0,a5
   100bc:       6422                    ld      s0,8(sp)
   100be:       0141                    addi    sp,sp,16
   100c0:       8082                    ret
```

What I don't understand is the meaning of the machine code in objdump output.
For example, the first instruction `addi` is translated into `.....0010011` according to [this page](https://msyksphinz-self.github.io/riscv-isadoc/html/rvi.html#addi), (while this is not an official spec). However, the dumped hex is `1141`. `1141` can only represent 2 bytes, but the instruction should be 32-bit, 4bytes.

I guess I am missing some points, but how should I read the output of objdump for riscv?

Comment: Those seem to be the [16 bit compressed instructions](https://five-embeddev.com/riscv-isa-manual/latest/c.html).

Comment: Thank you. I checked the spec of conpressed addi then i've found the hex matches that. Can I know if an instruction is compeessed or not by objdump?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, if it's 2 bytes it's compressed.

Comment: My point is that is there a way to show `c.addi` instead of just `addi` in objdump output?

Comment: Don't think so, but if you want binutils is open source and it looks easy to add such an option.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell objdump to show compressed ([16-bit](https://five-embeddev.com/riscv-isa-manual/latest/c.html)) instructions by using `-M no-aliases` in this way

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d -M no-aliases
```

In that case, instructions starting with `c.` are compressed ones.

Unfortunately that will also disable some other aliases, making the asm less nice to read if you're used to them.  You can just look at the number of bytes (2 vs. 4) in the hexdump to see if it's a compressed instruction or not.